# "Unrecognized as command" message when trying to call Java program from command line

Tags: java, command, command-line-arguments

I am unable to call my java program from the command line.
I keep getting this message:

> "InitArray is not recognized  as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file."

I can read the directory with the 'dir' command and see the program 
that I am trying to launch but cannot get past this error message!

Here is what I see: C:\Users\myName\Java_WorkSpace>
And then I enter: InitArray 5 0 4

Again, I can see this program in the directory but I cannot 
access it.
WHAT AM I DOING WRONG???

Here is the program code:

```
public class InitArray 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // check number of command-line arguments
    if ( args.length != 3)
        System.out.println(
    "Error: Please re-enter the entire command, including\n" +
    "an array size, initial value and increment.");
    else
    {
    int arrayLength = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
    int[] array = new int[arrayLength];

    int initialValue = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int increment = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    // calculate value for each array element
    for ( int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++ )
        array[counter] = initialValue + increment * counter;

    System.out.printf("%s%8s\n", "Index", "Value");

    // display array index and value
    for ( int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++ )
        System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", counter, array[counter]);
    } // end else
} // end main
} // end class InitArray
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to type `java` first to call the Java executable.

Try this:

`java InitArray 5 0 4`

Answer (score 1):

Basically when using the Command line java you have to use - `java`.

For example you call your app from CMD using this -

```
java InitArray 5 0 4
```

If you bundle the files in a jar then the way of calling it is -

```
java -jar InitArray 5 0 4
```

Comment: @ Duli-chan,Thanks for taking the time to help. I hava placed 'java' before the call to 'InitArray' and now I am getting this error message: 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. This is what the command line looks like: C:\Users\Peter\Java_WorkSpace>java InitArray 5 0 4

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are using Windows.

Here is how you fix your problem:

- Get JDK from java. This [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) should get you to the download page. Install windows 32 or 64 bit whatever is appropriate for you system. Install it.
- Ensure the jdk is in your PATH by running `java -version` in command line.

  - If you get **"'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"** you need to add jdk to your path.
  - Navigate to C:/Program Files/Java/*your_jdk*/bin and look for **java.exe**. Right click java.exe, click on properties, and copy the filepath.
  - Open command prompt, run `SET PATH="%PATH%;path_to_java"`

    - To paste into command prompt, right click the icon in the top left, navigate to edit, then paste
  - Run `java -version` again and check to see that it is working.
- Go to the directory with your java source file in windows explorer.
- Hold shift, right click the whitespace by the contents of the folder, and click "open command window here".
- Run javac "name_of_your_java_file.java"
- Run java "same_name" 5 0 4

Happy java! Eclipse does all this for you by the way. Look into using an IDE.